# Rails in_time_zone странные результаты

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Имеется поле created_at: Fri, 26 Oct 2018 13:22:40 MSK +03:00. 
Для примера возьму ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Lisbon'].formatted_offset > "+00:00".
Соответственно created_at.in_time_zone('Lisbon') тоже ожидаю ответ со смещением 00:00. Получаю: Fri, 26 Oct 2018 11:22:40 WEST +01:00 (вместо 10:22 и 00:00 соответственно) такое наблюдается на некоторых временных зонах (а на большинстве - все нормально). Как это можно обойти и почему вообще in_time_zone так работает?
Дополню. У Лиссабона действительно временная зона +01:00 и результат получаю правильный, но почему же utc_offset и formatted_offset показывают "+00:00" и ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Lisbon'].to_s => "(GMT+00:00) Lisbon"?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если такая проблема у кого будет, получить правильное смещение временной зоны по имени можно так:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone).formatted_offset
```